# c# get method from inherited class

Tags: c#, class, methods

we have the classes:

```
    class A
    {

    }

    class B:A
    {
      public void metod(){}
    }
```

and

```
    static class C
    {
        static void met(B clas)
        {
            A test = clas as B;
            // is it any way to get method "metod " from B via test?
        }
    }
```

I know that this look like nonsense but the idea is right, I cannot make B object in C class.

Comment: Why are you casting `B` to `A` and then trying to call a method of `B`?!

Comment: I agree with your question it does look like nonsense.

Comment: So how I can see, it is impossible,
i cannot cast like B, because in real i have three classes and i don't from which this method is called.

Comment: @konopiuxkonopiux - after seeing acceptance answer..i m not getting what you are trying to achieve...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Child can access parent through `base`. For e.g.

```
base.SomeMethod();
```

because when inheriting child knows who parent is and that parent class becomes base

but there is no keyword like `child` because base does not know which class will inherit it.

A child can have a single parent but a parent can have one or more child.

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert it back like this and than you can access

```
Base derivedInstance = new Derived();
Derived child= (Derived)derivedInstance; 
child.Callmethod();
```

in short

```
   A test = clas as B;
   ((B)test).method();
```

Comment: Can't he simply call `clas.method();`

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal = no because its of type A and for type A method is not avaialbe which is in B

Answer (score 0):

You can cast test to B, or simply use the variable declared as B in the first place:

```
((B)test).metod();
```

or

```
clas.metod();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 class A
    {
      public virtual void method(){}
    }
    class B:A
    {
      public override void method(){}
    }
 and 
    static class C
    {
    static void met(B clas)
      {
        A test = clas as B;
        test.method(); //this may be what you want?
       }
    }
```